# How to tighten a nut in a tank that can not be reached?

Tags: plumbing

I got a water tank (like [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/7tWVFu7qLpBpNUFn9)) installed which is leaking from an unused outlet at the bottom. The fitting is as shown in the figure below, it looks somewhat like a bulkhead installed in reverse:

[image]

Pic from outside:

[image]

I think that the water is seeping out from either side of the outside gasket. The obvious way to fix this is to tighten the nut on the inside.
However I can't tighten the nut from the inside because the tank has a narrow opening and is very deep. I will have to drain it, disconnect it, move it on its side and then crawl into it, which is a lot of work and risks damaging the tank.

I am asking if anyone has ideas or knows of tools which provide an easier way to do this.

Comment: Is that a nut next to the pie plug??

Comment: @JACK It seems joined to the threaded pipe. Like I said it is like a bulkhead fitting

Comment: Any chance of tightening the plug, which will turn the pipe and maybe not the inside nut, ?

Comment: @JACK Yes I can tighten the plug or even directly move the outside 'nut', which will move the entire assembly, however I don't know how to prevent the inside nut from rotating.

Comment: How deep is the tank?

Comment: @PlatinumGoose Around 6 feet, a few inches less.

Comment: If this is a new installation I think you should be talking to the folks that installed this for getting this leak fixed.

Comment: @MichaelKaras It is rightfully the responsibility of the plumber who installed it. However he is out of the town for at least two days. I was hoping there might be a way for me to do it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Use a deep well socket and two 36" extensions. Tape them together really good otherwise you might have to fish them out with a magnet if they come apart. If the nut is at a right angle then fasten a long handle (piece of pipe works well) to a ratchet wrench.

[image: 36" Extension]

[image: deep well sockets]

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem when I re-purposed some 45 gallon plastic drums to collect rainwater.

My solution was to use a broom handle to hold the socket - bear in mind I had to get the nut & washer down there and get it to start on the thread...

Comment: I ended up removing the entire fitting and reinstalled it the other way around, so the nut is now on the outside. This makes it much easier to service and also to install, using a wire to guide the fitting to its hole and then tightening the nut from the outside.